# Column wise append elements in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to export arrays to csv file, but for each of the three columns `number1` `number2` `number3` each element is stored row wise.

What I am getting is :

```
number1,number2,number3

[0 1 2 3],[10 8 9 2],[3 4 5 3]
```

What I need is :

```
number1,number2,number3

0,10,3
1,8,4
2,9,5
3,2,3
```

code:

```
with open('names.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['number1', 'number2', 'number3']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows({'number1': number1, 'number2': number2, 'number3': number3})
```

I tried transposing the arrays but it did not help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to combine the numbers

```
import csv

with open('names.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['number1', 'number2', 'number3']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    number1, number2, number3 = [0, 1, 2, 3], [10, 8, 9, 2], [3, 4, 5, 3]
    
    for i, j, k in zip(number1, number2, number3):
        writer.writerow({'number1': i, 'number2': j, 'number3': k})
```